# Upload de Imagem com PHP retornando um Erro: undefined index error

Tags: php, upload, image

Boa noite a todos, estou utilizando um script que eu tenho e que sempre usei para upload de imagens
só que quando escolho algumas imagens ele retorna o erro `undefined index error`

o único problema é que em 80% dos casos funciona normal fiz um var dump do $_FILES para ver o que acontece

no caso normal

```
array (size=1)
  'foto' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'interlogo.jpg' (length=13)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php586.tmp' (length=22)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 13800
```

no caso com erro

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

a única diferença de uma foto para outra é o tamanho, uma tem 130k e outra 3 mega. quando da o erro ele da bem nas linhas das variáveis

```
$foto_name=$_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$foto=$_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
```

alguém já teve este erro ?

Comment: Cheque os valores `upload_max_filesize` e `post_max_size` no seu `php.ini`. Se os valores forem menor do que o arquivo que estiver tentando fazer upload, a variável global `$_FILES` ficará vazia.

Comment: chequei e ambos estão com 20 mega sendo que o arquivo só tem 3

Comment: o post size estava em 2 lugares no php.ini um com 3 mega outro com 20 , resolvido .Obrigado

Comment: Mesmo com seu problema resolvido, publiquei uma resposta um pouco mais detalhada, assim se alguém tiver o mesmo problema que o seu e encontrar sua pergunta, terá a solução mais visível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema pode ser com a diretiva `post_max_size` do [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php).

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size):

> [...] Se o dados postados forem maiores que post_max_size então as
>   variáveis [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php) [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php) e [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php) ficarão vazias. [...]

Vale checar também a diretiva `upload_max_filesize`, já que para fazer uploads de arquivos grandes, o `max_post_size` precisa ser maior que [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize).

Comment: obrigado pelo esforço ^^